# VB.NET - Form is stuck

Tags: vb.net, forms, debugging

I have written a program and have used it (in debug mode) multiple times to test it out sometimes adding code and/or changing it. After a while any code I wrote or new buttons or features I added to the form would not appear while debugging. I don't know what circumstances led to this.

The only solution I found was to rewrite my code from scratch, however, the problem came back after a while. I don't know what is going on and I can't move on without starting all over again.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Are you talking about Edit and Continue. In Visual Studio 2005 onwards you can edit your code while your debugging *. There are certain things you cant do, for example edit a function that contains a Lambda. You cant add buttons to a form while debugging & etc. May I suggest you pick up a free book from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try rebuilding your entire solution, I believe to do this you must right-click on the project and there should be a menu option that says "rebuild solution". Try that.